how to implement functionality of iphone camera lens zooming?
enter image description here
how to implement iphone camera lens zooming functionality in swift xcode?
i tried several swift code available in online, but didn't leads to implement like original.
if any have tried these, please comment.
func fetchAvailableCameras() {
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera, .builtInTelephotoCamera, .builtInUltraWideCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified)
availableCameras = discoverySession.devices
        for camera in availableCameras {
            if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                // Adjust to actual zoom factors if needed. Here it's just for demo purposes
                zoomFactors.append(1.0) // Assume 1x is available by default
                zoomFactors.append(camera.minAvailableVideoZoomFactor) // Minimum zoom factor
                zoomFactors.append(camera.maxAvailableVideoZoomFactor) // Maximum zoom factor
                print("****Camera: \(camera.localizedName), ****Position: \(camera.position.rawValue),****lensAperture: \(camera.lensAperture),****isAutoFocusRangeRestrictionSupported: \(camera.isAutoFocusRangeRestrictionSupported),videZoomfactor:\(camera.videoZoomFactor)")
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}

